# iOS SDK - Track viewDidLoad method

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, categories

I am working on a SDK, where I will have to make a call to our server whenever `viewDidLoad` method of any `UIViewController` is called in the app integrated with our SDK. I am trying to use Categories as shown below:

```
#import "DymmyViewController.h"

@interface DymmyViewController ()
@end

@protocol DummyDelgate;
@interface UIViewController (DummyAddition)
-(void)viewDidLoad;
@end

@implementation DymmyViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
@end

@implementation UIViewController (DummyAddition)

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    //server call
}
@end
```

Nothing happens with this and I get a warning saying "`Category is implementing a method which will also be implemented by its primary class`"

I understand this is not the way to get this done. Is there any other way I can do this? May be using `NSNotification`?

Comment: Why are you doing this -----interface UIViewController (DummyAddition)
-(void)viewDidLoad;
@end
?

Comment: 1) It makes no sense to declare `viewDidLoad` in a class category since `UIViewController` already has such a method. 2) Never attempt to override an existing method in a category. It is undefined behavior. Categories should only add new methods/properties, never attempt to replace them.

Comment: rather have a base viewcontroller that all your viewcontrollers inherit from, and do whatever you need to do in the base one

Comment: What do you exactly want?

Comment: just do what analytics sdks do. Give a method to user which he will call in every viewDidLoad. Why complicating things

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to use protocols and delegates. Delegated are good techniques to respond from one class to another class.

**DummyView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class DummyView;

@protocol DummyViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)addItemViewController;
@end

@interface DummyView : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <DummyViewDelegate> delegate;


@end
```

**DummyView.m**

```
#import "DummyView.h"

@interface DummyView ()
@end

@implementation DummyView

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)backButtonClicked:(id)sender {
   [self.delegate addItemViewController];
}
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DummyView.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <DummyViewDelegate>

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    DummyView *acController;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    acController.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)addItemViewController{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make a tracking view controller available in the SDK. The app dev should then make all of their view controllers of this base type. You might need a couple of base classes (e.g. if you're also using TableViewControllers).

In SDK:

```
@interface TrackingViewController : UIViewController
@end

@implementation TrackingViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Make the call here
    // ....
}
```

In app:

```
#import "SDK.h"

@interface MyViewController : TrackingViewController ...
```